# Regex + Python - Converting multiple commands into one or fewer commands

Tags: python, regex

Does anyone have an idea on how to convert the following commands into one or fewer commands?

```
variable = re.search("[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-' ]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+", variable).group(0)
variable = re.sub(" {2,}", " ", variable)
variable = re.sub("'{2,}", "'", variable)
variable = re.sub("\-{2,}", "-", variable)
```

Kind Regards,

Marian

Comment: I guess it would help a great deal if you posted the strings you are actually trying to match.

Comment: I am trying to match something like "Blabla's bla-bla1345", for example. Only alphanumeric are allowed. And space, -, ', but not consecutive and not at the start or end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a start:

```
variable = re.search("[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-' ]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+", variable).group(0)
variable = re.sub("([ '\-])\\1+", "\\1", variable)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! :)

Btw, can you please explain this part `"([ '\-])\\1+", "\\1"` ?

Comment: `\1` (or `\\1` because I had to double-escape it) is a reference to the first capture group. That's why I put the '[ '\-]' in parenthesis - to make it a capture group. Now I can repeat it anywhere (in my matches *and* in my replaces) using \1. I can refer to the second group I define (if I had one) with \2, to the third with \3, etc.

Comment: Also, since you're new to stack overflow, I'll kindly remind you to mark this question as answered. :) People here don't like it when askers leave questions unanswered and may not answer your questions in the future if you have a low accepted answers rating. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time :) Also, I know I sound kinda silly, but how do I mark my question as answered?

Comment: More precisely, mark this *answer* as **accepted**; it's that green checkmark icon on the left.  By the way, you can use Python's raw strings to cut down on the backslash-itis: `re.sub(r"([ '\-])\1+", r"\1", variable)`